# How to define data types directly in a namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces

What I'm trying to find out whether you can have something like underneath or not:

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    public string myString;
}
```

I couldn't find anything that explained this, probably because of my terrible searching keywords. Could anyone tell me if there is a way to do this or not?

*If this **is** possible, I may have goofed up something. Either way, I'd like to know.*

I wanted to know how to do this because I want to have access to this in the whole namespace without having to go something.myString when I'm inside a different class. This was something that seemed logical in my eyes, but it's apparently not possible.

Comment: That's not possible. But maybe you'll find help when telling us why you would do this.

Comment: Take a look at [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx) about `namespace`.

Comment: you don't have to write `something.myString` if it bothers you. Just use required namespace with `using something;`

Comment: `something.MyString` may be what you want (stylistically?) but it will help loads when debugging.

Comment: That should work, Nino. Thanks!

Comment: Next time try to ask question regarding problem (e.g. "How to avoid having to write myNamespace.someClass.myString to access myString") , not attempted solution (How to define data types directly in namespace.. huh?). See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295).

Comment: While it is supported by the .NET (you can have "global" methods and fields in .NET), this feature isn't supported in C#. See for example [.NET 2.0 IL Assembler](https://books.google.it/books?id=oAcCRKd6EZgC&pg=PA220&lpg=PA220&dq=ilasm+methods+outside+classes&source=bl&ots=KBXiaItZ6r&sig=S_BqozlqttnU4JTLNZ8u8pqq024&hl=it&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiC2OH1iNvSAhXCtBoKHbLuB-gQ6AEINjAD#v=onepage&q=ilasm%20methods%20outside%20classes&f=false)

Comment: @Nino `something` is not a namespace, it's a class, in OP's example, because MyString cannot be defined as a string without a class.

Comment: @Andrew, i know, but that was just one example how to avoid writing `something.myString`. It is pretty ambiguous request from OP and so is my comment. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't declare field *directly* in the `namespace`:

```
    // doesn't compile
    namespace myNamespace
    {
        public string myString; // <- syntax error
    }
```

but you can *emulate* such a syntax with a help of `using static` (C# 6.0+):

```
    namespace MyLibrary 
    {
        // put myString within a static class
        public static class MyStorage 
        {
            // let turn field into property
            public static string myString {get; set;}
        }
    }
```

Then use the static class with `using static`:

```
    // please, notice "using static"
    using static MyLibrary.MyStorage;

    namespace myNamespace
    {
        public class MyClass 
        {
            public void MyMethod() 
            {
                myString = "abc"; // as if it has been declared in the namespace

                string test = myString;  
                ...
            }
        } 

    }
```